# Mapbox Dynamic Creation of markers

Tags: java, android, mapbox, markers, mapbox-android

so here's the thing, i am trying to create an android map app that allows the user to look for nearby Companies/Enterprises as well as when a marker is dropped on the map. The dynamic markers get created however only the last one is clickable (aka display the title for example). The landmark data i am using is static and is put inside of a list. i have no idea what's causing it especially since as i said before only the last created allows for clicking.

```
@Override
public boolean onMapClick(@NonNull LatLng point) {
    final List<MarkerOptions> markers = new ArrayList();
    LatLng p = new LatLng();
    map.clear();
    createDestination(point);

    for (int i = 0; i < listPos.size(); i++) {
        double resultLon = point.getLongitude() - listPos.get(i).getLon();
        double resultLat = point.getLatitude() - listPos.get(i).getLat();

        if (resultLat >= -0.05 && resultLat <= 0.05 && resultLon >= -0.05 && resultLon <= 0.05) {
            createDestination(point);
            p.setLatitude(listPos.get(i).getLat());
            p.setLongitude(listPos.get(i).getLon());
            markers.add(new MarkerOptions().position(p));
            map.addMarker(markers.get(i).title(listPos.get(i).getName()));
        } else {
            map.clear();
            createDestination(point);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

this is my mapclick aka marker drop to create dynamic markers.
i would appreaciate any answers especially since i have been stuck at this for the last couple days. Thank you for taking the time to read.

Comment: Hi Adam!
`   markers.add(new MarkerOptions().position(p));
            map.addMarker(markers.get(i).title(listPos.get(i).getName()));` looks weird, 
I'd replace it with 
,?> marker = new MarkerOptions().position(p);  markers.add(marker);
marker..title(listPos.get(i).getName());
            map.addMarker(marker);

But anyway. Is that correct that you're clear the map  inside the loop?

Comment: okay i will try that out and see the result. darn! now i see where the mistake is the clear it keeps killing my markers. THANK YOU SO MUCH THIS MAY  OR MAY NOT MAKE THINGS WORK
Edit: well no the clear didn't do much but i still think it's a good start frankly

Comment: Your code is creating and adding all your markers _every time_ the map is tapped. Is this your intention? I'd strongly recommend against doing this as it's rather inefficient and can easily lead to wonky interactivity issues like the one you've described. Instead, I would encourage you to follow a pattern like the one used in this example: https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/symbol-layer-info-window/